# Highcharts Bar Chart - Labels Not Appearing in Bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I've been playing around with a highcharts bar chart and noticed some strange behavior.  If I have a long name in the x axis (the categories), and if I have labels enabled to show up on the bars, not all the labels will appear.  If I remove the long x axis name, then the label that wasn't appearing on the bar before will suddenly appear.  I have a working Jsfiddle example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/p55t0bmf/ (notice label isn't appearing for one of the bars, should say 5 but nothing is there)

I placed a long name in the categories section to trigger this behavior:

```
xAxis: {
        categories: ["LONG NAME THAT WILL BREAK US"] 
       }
```

Does anyone know why this would be happening, and is there a way to fix this behavior (without resorting to short x axis names of course)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set [`allowOverlap`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.allowOverlap) to true. When you have longer xAxis labels, then you have less horizontal space. Labels have padding which can overlap and hide some of them. Anyway, your demo works for me exactly the same way with or without long xAxis category.

Demo with all labels: https://jsfiddle.net/p55t0bmf/1/

Answer (score 0):

`stacking` option cause this problem. If you set the stacking, then highchart change the label opacity automatically.

Solution : Remove stacking options from chart, if you dont need or write css to override label opacity.

Comment: Unfortunately I need stacking enabled.